# App cache is not working when running an application in localhost?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file with manifest defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache" type="text/cache-manifest">
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
   Sample app
</body>
</html>
```

and a manifest file like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
*
```

usually, firefox should prompt me to store the files in the browser chache?

its not prompting and also nothing is getting cached, when i look into the dom, using firebug's DOM tab.

Can anybody tell me what is happening here or am i missing something?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The manifest file must be served up with the special mime-type `text/cache-manifest`. If not the browser will probably not take the manifest file into account. So you better set up a local http server and configure the right mime type. For apache you can add this to your .htaccess

```
AddType     text/cache-manifest     .manifest
```

Read the following article for more details: [Testing Your Offline Applications](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/testing-your-offline-applications.html#fbid=BpDrMYhDzKB)